# how to populate Django hidden input field of modelform with info from template?

Tags: ajax, django-forms, django-templates, hidden-field

I've seen this asked a few times but have never seen an answer. I have a Django ModelForm with a hidden input field. I need to use info from my template for the hidden field - the 'send_to' field in this case.

So I have the form where users can write a subject and a message, and I want to autopopulate the "to" field.

This is my modelform:

```
class MessageForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Message
    fields = ['subject', 'message', 'send_to']
    widgets = {'send_to': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

The 'send_to' part needs to be populated with info from my template.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'send' %}" id="commiserator" name="{{ c.id }}" class="write-to-user" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h3>To: {{ c.username }}</h3>
{% csrf_token %}

{{message.as_p}}
<input id="commiserator" class="write-to-user" type="submit" value="Send">
```

Right now {{c.username}} is just displayed as html. I want it to be used as form input for the hidden field, but I have no idea how to do that.

The form is being sent to the view with Ajax so I would like to make it so that the hidden information is populated before Ajax sends the data. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly from the template. But you have a couple of options.

In your view where you instantiate your message ModelForm to pass to the template, you could pre-populate the value of the send_to field. This should then render it in the template with that same value. This is probably what you want.

Your other option is to exclude send_to from the ModelForm, and to add it hard-coded as a hidden field in the form in your template. `{{message.as_p}}` will then only render the visible fields.